# How secure is a connection using OpenVPN?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openvpn

So I just set up an openVPN sever inside a public subnet of my VPC to connect to my private sub ets, following instructions on https://openvpn.net/

I do not have a domain, so I just use the elastic Ip on the Instance.
Everything works great.

However, before I use this I would like to know the vulnerabilities. I cannot find documentation anywhere about exactly how safe such a connection is.
Obviously the passwords need to be secured, and a security group should limit access, But is it safe enough to transport passwords and private customer information?

I thought ssl usually require a certificate to really be safe?

The exact steps I followed are out lined in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWqRrMGHJQg

Its 5 mins, 2.5min if you watch it 2x;

Comment: openvpn does use a certificate. you can have certs on the server or server and client. but if you actually check that they are valid is a separate thing

Comment: If you followed the correct directions, you should have already set up OpenVPN with certificates.

Comment: OpenVPN can be configured either with certificates or with a static, pre-shared key. Could you clarify which you've done—do you have a `secret` directive in your config, or do you have `cert`, `ca`, and `key`?

Comment: I didn't set any of that up, but it could have come pre-configured in the AMI i used on aws marketplace?

Comment: Please post your configuration (obfuscating IPs/passphrases/....). Should be some .conf file in /etc/openvpn.

Comment: That video seems to show installing **OpenVPN-AS**, which is a commercial product that does a bunch of stuff for you, compared to the Open source package.  I am not sure what the defaults are, but it seems likely that it would generate keys as part of the setup.